# JSON Reading Object Values

Tags: java, android, spotify

I have a JSON response from Spotify that I'm trying to read from. And in my java code I am getting the 'name' value for the album object, and not for the tracked object.  Here is the response: https://pastebin.com/fcvTzJJv

Towards the bottom of the JSON Response, there is a name field that says "Money in the Grave", that is what I want to get from the JSON, instead of "The Best in the world pack" which is under the name of the album.

Here is the code that reads this response:

```
 try
            {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result);
                JSONObject tracks = obj.getJSONObject("tracks");
                JSONArray items = tracks.getJSONArray("items");

                for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
                {
                    //album object
                    JSONObject album = items.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("album");
                    //SHOULD be getting the images array but does not

                    //artist array
                    JSONArray artists = album.getJSONArray("artists");


                    //gets the necessary artist information
                    for(int j = 0; j < artists.length(); j++)
                    {
                        JSONObject artist = artists.getJSONObject(j);
                        songLists.add(artist.getString("name") +  " - " +album.getString("name"));
                    }
                }
            }
```

With the above code, I'm getting "The Best in the World Pack", and not "Money in the Grave". Could someone help explain how to get the track's name, and not the albums name. Thanks

Comment: put all the JSON data in your question

Comment: it's a lot, but I'll include the whole response

Comment: You can use https://pastebin.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 for(int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++)
            {

                 JSONObject values  = items.getJSONObject(i);
                   String name= values.getString("name");
                    System.out.println(name+"          nameee");
                //artist array
                JSONArray artists = album.getJSONArray("artists");
  }
```

> this will work for you and will return  "Money In The Grave (Drake ft. Rick Ross)"

Answer (score 0):

**You can try like this and it will give that track name**

```
String response = yourJSonData;

try {
            JSONObject jsonObject =  new JSONObject(response);
            Log.e("data","data---"+response);
           JSONArray jsArrItems = jsonObject.getJSONObject("tracks").getJSONArray("items");
            Log.e("data","data---222>>"+jsArrItems.getJSONObject(0).getString("name")+"<<>>"+jsArrItems);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

**If you have `items` as `JSONArray` more than 1 then can use the loop as well**

Answer (score 0):

get name like tems.getJSONObject(i).getString("name") in your items loop as name you are looking is in items array object not in artist object.